# How to apply different weights to different dimensions for distance metric in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, euclidean-distance

I'm trying to modify a minkowski distance that can either be euclidean or manhattan in which each dimension can be weighted differently. I've seen posts that give an answer using scipy that appear to answer a slightly different question. In my case, my distance metric will only have 2 dimensions and I want to be able to control the weights on each dimension.

He is what I have now. I would like to find a more numpy/ scipy way of doing this:

```
t1 = np.array([2,4])
t2 = np.array([1,2])

def weighted_minkowski(t1,t2,w = .3, p = 2):
    return np.sqrt(w*((t1[0]-t2[0])**p)+(1-w)*((t1[1]-t2[1])**p))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
def weighted_minkowski(t1, t2, w=.3, p=2):
    return np.sqrt([w, 1-w] @ (t1 - t2)**p)
```

Explanation: form the weight vector `[w, 1-w]`, and take dot product of that with the difference of the two vectors raised to `p`th power.

I'm assuming Python 3.5 or newer, which has the matrix multiplication operator @. Applied to vectors, this gives the dot product. In earlier Python versions, you can use `np.dot`.